# Need help with Salesforce API's

Tags: apex, api, webservices

(Editing the question to be more specific)

I am pretty new to API development so I was hoping if I can get some help with my task.
I have a task where a third part API need to Integrate with Salesforce, passing some parameters which will used to create a new record for a custom object.

I did some reading on the knowledge materials and came up with below solution but was hoping if the experts can help me with my questions.

1. Create a new Apex Web service.
2. Generate the WSDL for this service which will be invoked by the 3rd party application.

Am I correct in following this solution or can this task be accomplished in better ways too?

Is there some other setup setting that needs to be done which I might be missing?

Comment: [Trailhead API Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/api_basics)

Answer (score 3):

Both APIs are roughly analogous. The REST API is geared towards mobile access (mobile apps and websites), while SOAP access is more geared towards desktop and server environments, which typically have better support for SOAP (e.g. Java, PHP).

You can use either in most situations, but you'll want to research which will be easier in your particular platform. REST, however, usually has the benefit of smaller requests (faster, uses less bandwidth), which is better for mobile devices, but doesn't have all of the features of the SOAP API.

As far as the Connected App goes, it is uniquely used for the REST API mechanism. SOAP uses a more traditional username/password method, while the REST API handles authentication for you (you never need the username or password from the user, but instead get a token that grants you access).